# HTML file can't find bootstrap CSS File

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

I'm currently following a tutorial word for word but for some reason my css files aren't being detected by my html. I also tried using the full file path and that didn't effect the styling either.

This is my encounter with spring boot and bootstrap.[image]

Comment: Your link looks good enough. Can't suggest more without looking at your file structure. Add a screenshot of your file structure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `./css/*.min.css`? This should work if you have a the "css" folder on the same level as your .html file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed node_modules your link should define like this to access bootstrap CSS file

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

or you can refer this site for more info "https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bug in my IDE and I just switched over to IntelliJ.